# array_values() causes a Notice

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting this notice and I don't know what to do about it:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Filename: models/Connection_model.php
>
> Line Number: 123

Line Number 123 is the following code:

```
echo array_values($this->errors)[0];
```

What is wrong with that line? I am just trying to echo the first value of an array.

Comment: Sounds like `$this->errors` is empty so `array_values` is returning an empty array. Meaning there is no index 0.

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `$this->errors` is empty. You would want to wrap this line in an if statement that checks that it's set and that it has elements:

```
if (!empty($this->errors)) {
    echo array_values($this->errors)[0];
}
```